# <%@ MasterType TypeName="ggg.Web.Main" %>dll". Illegal characters in path

Tags: asp.net

this is kinda wierd.

**I have a couple projects:**

**ggg.Web** (main WAP project)

**ggg.Web.Controls** (Plain C# project that holds any custom controls .cs)

When I try to compile ggg.Web.Controls, I get this error:

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="ggg.Web.Main" %>dll". Illegal characters in path.
```

It's referring to the project ggg.Web.Controls project but I've gone through every class and there is no <%@ MasterType TypeName="ggg.Web.Main" %> code in any of those classes.

Only in the ggg.Web .aspx pages do I have that kind of directive specified at the top of some of my .aspx pages.  ggg.Web references and uses ggg.Web.Controls.

I've tried to clean my solution, close out VS....but still nothing.  This is the only error coming up during compile.
C# Web Developer

Answer (score 0):

Try closing all windows, restarting Visual Studio and see if the problem persist. If it does copy/paste the error from Output pane here.

Comment: Tried that and also went through every project to make sure any file doesn't have an error and none do.

Answer (score 0):

It was a corrupt project. I recreated that project, dumped back in the files and violà.